# Undefined method 'about' for nill class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-attributes

I have two table: `User` has one `Account`, `Account` belongs_to `User`. When I want to get some value from field '`about`' (table `Accounts`), I have a problem '`undefined method` `about`' for `nil:NilClass`'. The challenge is to get the list of followers and gain their avatar or information 'about' from another table and output it in View.

My method in controller

```
 def list_of_follower
   @followers_id = Follow.select("follower_id ").where("followable_id = ?", current_user)
   @followers = User.where("id in (?)", @followers_id)
   @followables_id = Follow.select("followable_id").where("follower_id = ?", current_user)
   @followables = User.where("id in (?)", @followables_id)
end
```

View list_of_follower.html.haml

```
%h1 My followers
 - @followers.each do |f|
  %ul.list-group
    %li.list-group-item
      %p=f.name
      %p=f.account.about
%h1 I'm follower
- @followables.each do |followable|
  %ul.list-group
%li.list-group-item
  %p=followable.name
  %p=followable.account.about
```

Create_Accounts.rb

```
class CreateAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :accounts do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.text :about
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
 end
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 acts_as_followable
 acts_as_follower
 acts_as_liker
 has_one :account
 has_many :posts
 has_many :comments

accepts_nested_attributes_for :account
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

def email_required?
  false
end

def email_changed?
  false
end

 validates :login, :email, uniqueness: true
end
```

Account.rb

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
 end
```

table `User` content is displayed without problems (work requests), but the contents of the table associated with it does not displayed, what is the problem?

Comment: Run `rails console` create a new user via `user = User.create(<options>)`, and run `user.account.nil?`, if the answer is true, new users don't have default accounts being created, and hence you have to build that. I'll post that answer, if this is the case.

Comment: Yes, answer is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, a problem is not every user has an account.
You can try this:

```
%p=f.account.try(:about)
```